# What is the difference between 'mv' and 'cp' if you want to move a file?

Tags: command-line

If you want to move a file from one directory to another you can use either of the commands `mv` or `cp`. But what is the difference between the two, and when should one be used over the other?

Comment: cp will create a copy of the file/directory and is most definitely not the same as moving a file/directory.

Comment: here is detailed answer -> https://superuser.com/questions/101676/is-there-some-difference-between-mv-and-cp-rm-the-old-file-on-unix/101678?newreg=52b7920a1ca64a9db3cfb4e04eb1f83e

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `cp` command will **copy** your file(s) while the `mv` one will **move** them.

So, the difference is that `cp` will keep the old file(s) while `mv` won't.

Answer (score 1):

`mv` moves or renames a file or directory, while `cp` copies a file or directory.

`mv` deletes the source file or directory after moving it, while `cp` keeps the source file or directory intact.

`mv` does not change the inode number of the file or directory, while `cp` creates a new inode number for the copied file or directory.

`mv` does not access the file or directory data if the destination is on the same filesystem, while `cp` always reads and copies the file or directory data.